# Android Navigation Component with Transition from Drawerlayout

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-transitions, android-jetpack

Is it possible to change the transition effect from opening a fragment from a drawerlayout with the android navigation component. There is nothing in the android docs.

Answer (score 3):

Sarah! Yes, it is possible. You can add your custom listener to handle navigation item selection and add animation there. I had to add one myself, for other purposes, but it definitely fits as a solution for your task.

### How to:

1. Add layout with drawer. Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
   tools:openDrawer="start">

   <!-- Other views can be added here, or below -->

   <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
       android:id="@+id/nav_view"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_gravity="start"
       app:menu="@menu/menu_for_drawer" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

2. Find `NavigationView` by ID and assign it to a variable `private NavigationView navigationView` in your activity, that you may extract by using `findViewById(R.id.nav_view)`. This step is optional. You may find the view and assing naviation item selection listener without holding a reference to NavigationView;
3. Set navigation item selection listener:

```
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(menuItem -> {
           @IdRes
           int id = menuItem.getItemId();
           NavOptions.Builder optionsBuilder = new NavOptions.Builder();

           switch (id) {
               case R.id.first_menu_item_id: {
                   // Lets assume for the first menu item navigation is default
                   optionsBuilder
                           .setEnterAnim(R.anim.nav_default_enter_anim)
                           .setExitAnim(R.anim.nav_default_exit_anim)
                           .setPopEnterAnim(R.anim.nav_default_pop_enter_anim)
                           .setPopExitAnim(R.anim.nav_default_pop_exit_anim);
               }
               break;
               case R.id.second_menu_item_id: {
                   // Lets assume for the second menu item navigation is missing
                   // empty here
               }
               break;
               case R.id.thrid_menu_item_id: {
                   // Lets assume for the third menu item navigation is custom
                   optionsBuilder
                           .setEnterAnim(R.anim.slide_in_right)
                           .setExitAnim(R.anim.slide_out_left)
                           .setPopEnterAnim(R.anim.slide_in_left)
                           .setPopExitAnim(R.anim.slide_out_right);
               }
               break;
           }

           navController.navigate(id, null, optionsBuilder.build());
           
           // Do not forget to close the drawer
           // drawer.closeDrawers();
           return true;
       });
```

This should help! Any thoughts and questions are welcome!

---

In case you are interested in animations mentioned in example:

- `slide_in_left.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <translate android:fromXDelta="-100%" android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="300"/>
</set>
```

- `slide_in_right.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <translate android:fromXDelta="100%" android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="300"/>
</set>
```

- `slide_out_left.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <translate android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="-100%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="300"/>
</set>
```

- `slide_out_right.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <translate android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="100%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="300"/>
</set>
```

### Update (28 March 2020)

In case this solution doesn't work with the Drawer Menu try to use it **with** the following code.

Note that I placed `setNavigationItemSelectedListener` call at the end of the method due to `NavigationUI` functions sometimes **settings it's own listener**. That could also be the cause of problem.

There is a lot going on behind `NavigationUI` functions and if something doesn't work right check out implementation of the functions you use.

```
private void setupNavigation() {
        // Set custom toolbar as action bar
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        // Setup navigation with toolbar and drawer
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.main_nav_host_fragment);

        /* The set of destinations by id considered at the top level 
        of your information hierarchy. The Up button will not be displayed 
        when on these destinations. */
        Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(R.id.first_fragmentId_from_nav_graph, R.id.second_fragmentId_from_nav_graph, R.id.third_fragmentId_from_nav_graph)); 
        /* Configuration options for {@link NavigationUI} methods that interact with implementations of the
        app bar pattern */
        AppBarConfiguration configuration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(set).setDrawerLayout(drawer).build();

        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(toolbar, navController, configuration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, configuration);
        
        // And here you set the listener.
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(...);
    }
```

There are multiple calls to `NavigationUI` functions like `setupWithNavController` and `setupActionBarWithNavController`. The reason is that behind each one of them is added one more destination changed listener to navigation controller. See [addOnDestinationChangedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/NavController#addOnDestinationChangedListener(androidx.navigation.NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener)) for more information about the listener.

1. First call adds `new ToolbarOnDestinationChangedListener(toolbar, configuration)`;
2. Second call adds custom implementation of `NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener` that updates your navigation view in drawer correctly;
3. Third call adds `new ActionBarOnDestinationChangedListener(activity, configuration)`.

This configuration allows me to use a single application on a tablet with a Master-Detail pattern and on the phone as a usual application with Drawer Menu.

Referenced string resources are just:

```
<string name="navigation_drawer_open">Open navigation drawer</string>
<string name="navigation_drawer_close">Close navigation drawer</string>
```

But they are required for accessibility. It's very good to translate them if you support multiple languages. Basically anything used for accessibility is generally good to translate.

Comment: I tried your implementation.  This seems to be exactly what I'm looking for.  I have a drawer menu with several fragments that I want to add animation transition to.  I added the code to my onCreate method in my MainActivity.  The setNavigationItemSelectedListener is not getting called when I make a selection from the Drawer Menu.

Comment: @tzg, I suppose that `setNavigationItemSelectedListener ` is not getting called because navigation component either doesn't know about the Drawer or the way navigation was set up is causing the issue. I will extend the answer with the configuration used in my project.

Answer (score 2):

There is a simpler way. Internally `NavigationUI` builds the `NavOptions` like this:

```
    if (navController.getCurrentDestination().getParent().findNode(item.getItemId())
            instanceof ActivityNavigator.Destination) {
        builder.setEnterAnim(R.anim.nav_default_enter_anim)
                .setExitAnim(R.anim.nav_default_exit_anim)
                .setPopEnterAnim(R.anim.nav_default_pop_enter_anim)
                .setPopExitAnim(R.anim.nav_default_pop_exit_anim);

    } else {
        builder.setEnterAnim(R.animator.nav_default_enter_anim)
                .setExitAnim(R.animator.nav_default_exit_anim)
                .setPopEnterAnim(R.animator.nav_default_pop_enter_anim)
                .setPopExitAnim(R.animator.nav_default_pop_exit_anim);
    }
```

You can just create these directories yourself and override the defaults. In my case I had to create the `animator` folder (not `anim`!) in `/res/` and put 4 new animation files with these names in it. But maybe try both folders to be sure.
At the moment it works perfectly in a MaterialComponents Theme: the selected drawer item still get's highlighted and the appbar animation is still working too (unlike with some other methods).